# Laravel Blade using default variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

What I thought should've been really simple isn't just working

I have a blade file with

***datePicker.blade.php***

```
//this doesnt work
<input type="datetime-local" value='{{$value}}' />
//this works
{{ Form::text($name, $value, array_merge(['class' => 'form-control'], $attributes)) }}
```

the first one doesnt work, even if I change  to $events->event_date which works on the parent file

***parentfile.php***

```
{{ Form::adminDatePicker('event_date', old(event_date), DateTime) }}
```

any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check your `$value` date-time format. The date-time format for `datetime-local` should be as `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm`.

Comment: thats not it as i said there is no value being set

Comment: Another thing `value` is not evaluated because you're set inside a `single quote`. Check that, and I hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: ty but doesn't fix the problem